# PHP ImageMagick reading raw (nef) files returns smallest preview by default

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

I have the following working code;

```
$handle = fopen('C:\DSC_0306.NEF', 'r');
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImageFile($handle);
$im->setImageFormat('jpg');
$im->writeImage('c:\temp\result.jpg');
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

However, this returns the 1st preview image of 160x120 pixels.
I know there are other preview images:
Preview 1: image/jpeg, 160x120 pixels
Preview 2: image/tiff, 668x432 pixels
Preview 3: image/jpeg, 5184x3456 pixels

How would I extract those by default?

Comment: Try using `DSC_0306.NEF[2]` for example.